# When are the verbs "divide" and "multiply" synonyms, rather than antonyms?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, english, language

The answer has nothing to do with multiplicative inverses / reciprocals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you're referring to

> **Cellular reproduction** - This can occur through mitosis or meiosis in eukaryotes and binary fission in prokaryotes.
>
>  A cell divides into two, the effect of which is that the cell/ organism has multiplied in a reproductive sense.

Comment: You got it now.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about something which does not lose its nature, but rather creates a clone of itself when divided, then the number or quantity of that thing increases when divided, causing it to multiply in number.
(Example - cell division of one cell may create two identical cells.)

Comment: This is very similar to Phylyp's answer from a few hours ago, no?

Comment: @Wizard, try not to repost answers that have already been posted.